# Ionic ios access to it's plugins

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have made an app for `ios` and installed in my iphone. It has **Camera** plugin in it. **It works perfect in android**.

Also in iphone, as I run ionic `view` app (downloaded from appstore) it works perfect **into that** (first my phone asks about allowing access to camera), But not working in my own app.

**NOTE:** I installed `.ipa` from [diawi.com](https://www.diawi.com/)

**In ionic view app :**

[image]

But in my own app, Nothing! Doesn't work. Even `auto rotation` just works in ionic view app.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution:

Just add `--save` after installing a plugin. For example:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera --save
```

As in ionic package docs says:

> Cordova plugins may be installed locally, they may not be defined explicitly in your config.xml. To ensure that the build servers know about which plugins you need, use the --save flag when adding and removing plugins.

Also pay attention to [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#ios-quirks).